# AWS Lambda Python to Elasticsearch migration

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have stumbled on an issue when developing an AWS Lambda function with Python to export data from Kinesis data stream to elasticsearch. The issue is that I can't set the `_id` in elasticsearch to a custom one.

I tried some answers from similar questions, but to no avail.

Here is my Lambda function code:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64
import logging
from os import environ
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

# Configure the root logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Get the secret from AWS Secrets Manager
secret_name = 'elasticsearch'
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
res = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_name)

if 'SecretString' in res:
    secret = json.loads(res['SecretString'])  # Parse the secret as JSON
else:
    secret = json.loads(base64.b64decode(res['SecretBinary']))  # Parse the secret as JSON

# Create Elasticsearch client
es = Elasticsearch(
    secret['endpoint'],
    basic_auth=(secret['user'], secret['pswd'])
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Loading function')

    bulk_data = []
    
    for record in event['Records']:
        # Decode and parse the data from Kinesis
        data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data']).decode('utf-8'))
        
        # Prepare the document payload
        payload = {'document_type': data['metadata']['table-name']}
        
        # Get 'card_id' with a default value of None
        data_key = "data"
        if data_key in data:
            payload['card_id'] = data[data_key].get('id')
            
            # Get 'title' with a default value of None
            payload['title'] = data[data_key].get('title')
            
            # Get 'description' with a default value of None
            payload['description'] = data[data_key].get('description')
            
            # Set 'timestamp' with current datetime value
            payload['timestamp'] = datetime.now().isoformat()
            
            # Create the action for Elasticsearch bulk API
            action = {
                '_op_type': 'index',
                '_index': data['metadata']['schema-name'],
                '_id': payload['id'],
                '_source': payload
            }
            
            bulk_data.append(action)
        
    # Perform bulk indexing in Elasticsearch
    indexing = bulk(es, bulk_data, refresh=True)
    
    logger.info(f'{indexing}')
    logger.info(f'{data}')
    
    return f"Consumed: {len(event['Records'])} {'record' if len(event['Records']) <= 1 else 'records'}!"
```

And this is an example data from Kinesis (returned from `logger.info(f'{data}')`):

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":696969,
      "title":"Curabitur tempus vel dolor nec feugiat.",
      "description":"Curabitur tempus vel dolor nec feugiat.",
      "reporter_internal_user_id":172,
      "created_at":"2023-06-24T15:21:49Z"
   },
   "metadata":{
      "timestamp":"2023-06-26T14:32:52.138483Z",
      "record-type":"data",
      "operation":"load",
      "partition-key-type":"primary-key",
      "schema-name":"test",
      "table-name":"test-table-name"
   }
}
```

This is what the data looks like in the elasticsearch:

```
{
    "_index": "test",
    "_id": "Jnkc-IgBhSyLA19hiLAW",
    "_score": 12.333398,
    "_source": {
        "document_type": "test-table-name",
        "id": 696969,
        "title": "Curabitur tempus vel dolor nec feugiat.",
        "description": "<p>Curabitur tempus vel dolor nec feugiat.</p>",
        "timestamp": "2023-06-25T14:29:59.441402"
    }
}
```

Even though I try to set the `_id` to the `id` from the data,elasticsearch still sets it to a random generated mix of numbers and letters.

Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated!